# How to ngrx store.dispatch a value taken from an Observable?

Tags: angular, ngrx, angular2-observables, ngrx-store

I would like to dispatch a value taken from an Observable and currently this is how I'm doing it

```
search(): void {
  this.wordsService.getAll()
    .first()
    .subscribe((query: string) => {
      this.store.dispatch(
        this.wordsActions.search(query)
      );
    });
}
```

isn't there a *better* way to achieve the same, I don't know, something similar to this?

```
search(): void {
  this.store
    .flatMap(() => this.wordsService.getAll())
    .dispatch((query: string) =>  this.wordsActions.search(query));
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately not, the only way to retrieve a value from an Observable is to subscribe to it.

Comment: use can use ngrx-effects